# Can someone tell me a program that I can disable "seen" on facebook without ads?

Tags: facebook

I need a program to disable facebook seen feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no program (installing on desktop) as far as I know. But I am sure that you can find some extensions/plugins for Chrome browser (if this is your browser) if you search the chrome web store e.g. this [one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-seenblock/hpdbfhoobgcmiffaheiedgepeipfcjpb)